# How to shift all the views down except for the tab bar in tabViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uinavigationbar

In order to fix the overlapping of status bar and navigation bar in iOS 7+, i'm using this code inside `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` in `AppDelegate.m` :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    //some codes
    //.
    //.

    if([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7.0)
    {
        UIView *FakeNavBar = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 20)];
        FakeNavBar.backgroundColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x55BCAFF);

        float navBarHeight = 20.0;
        for (UIView *subView in self.window.subviews) {

            if ([subView isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {
                subView.frame = CGRectMake(subView.frame.origin.x, subView.frame.origin.y + navBarHeight, subView.frame.size.width, subView.frame.size.height - navBarHeight);
            } else {
                subView.frame = CGRectMake(subView.frame.origin.x, subView.frame.origin.y + navBarHeight, subView.frame.size.width, subView.frame.size.height);
            }
        }
        [self.window addSubview:FakeNavBar];
    }
}
```

It pushes all my controllers and views 20 pixels down and  and the overlapping problem gets fixed but when i reach my tab view controller scene, then the tab bar on the bottom goes out of view by 20 pixels.

So how can i keep the tab bar in its place while shifting everything else down?

It would also work if i could just shift up only the tab bar by 20 pixels.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to shift only the tab bar 20 pixels up but this may put some views behind the tab bar which is unwanted.

here is the code written inside `viewDidAppear` of my UITabBarController class :

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    CGRect newFrame = self.tabBar.frame;
    newFrame.origin.y -= 20;
    self.tabBar.frame = newFrame;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use the code below -

```
if([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7.0)
    {
        UIView *FakeNavBar = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 20)];
        FakeNavBar.backgroundColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x55BCAFF);

        float navBarHeight = 20.0;
        for (UIView *subView in self.window.subviews) {

            for (int index=0; index<[tabBarController.viewControllers count]; index++)
            {

                 if ([subView isKindOfClass:[[(UIViewController*)[tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:index] view] class]])
                 {
                     continue;
                 }
            }

            if ([subView isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {
                subView.frame = CGRectMake(subView.frame.origin.x, subView.frame.origin.y + navBarHeight, subView.frame.size.width, subView.frame.size.height - navBarHeight);
            } else {
                subView.frame = CGRectMake(subView.frame.origin.x, subView.frame.origin.y + navBarHeight, subView.frame.size.width, subView.frame.size.height);
            }
        }
        [self.window addSubview:FakeNavBar];
    }
```

Comment: Is this implemented in the same `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` in `AppDelegate.m` ?  because `tabBarController` is not recognized by compiler.

Comment: So what should i replace tabBarController with? It's not recognized by the compiler? Should i replace with an instance of my TabBarController class?

Comment: Are you added tabBarController from storyboard ? Yes then try this way UITabBarController * tabBarController =
   (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;

Comment: Yes it is added from storyboard and it's not my rootViewController.

Comment: So How and  where you added UITabBarController ? try to create outlet of that Tabbarcontroler

Comment: This is the code in `AppDelegate.m` file inside `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method, so here i'm not adding any UITabBarController. The app launches with a ViewController and then after some navigations it will get to the tab bar controller. So i'm not adding any UITabBarController inside AppDelegate. I hope i could clarify my question.

Comment: I added some codes to show this code is inside `AppDelegate.m`, not the UITabBarController class, please see the updated code.

Comment: remove above UITabBarController Code from appdelegate . and Try Change self.view frame 20px up(+) to all viewcontroller of tabviewcontroller . Write frame change code in didviewappear

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you're not using a navigation controller and you've manually added the navigation bar in your view. Is that right?

You should be able to achieve what you're after by adding a view with a size of the status bar at the top of the views of your view controllers in the storyboard.

Are you using auto-layout constraints? You could use them to make these views stick to the top of your views, have a fixed height of 20 pixels and a width equal to the width of the view controller's view.